# Deny all but only allow access from Angularjs on the same server

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, lumen

I have a Lumen backend and an Angularjs project on the same server without a virtual host. The way I access APIs is simply by the URL like www.example.com/api/public/get_some_data. I want to hide these endpoints from the public but only allow access from the Angularjs.

I tried adding this to the .htaccess in the api/public folder,

```
Order deny, allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

But Angular will be denied as well.

I access the endpoint from Angular like this,

```
function login(user) {
  return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'api/public/login/user',
    data: user,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  }).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
  }).catch(dataServiceError);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is client side framework. There is no difference for a server if a request comes from Angular application or anywhere else.

Access can be restricted based on some condition that can be satisfied by client side application, like request headers ([example](https://serverfault.com/a/575065)).

Security through obscurity is the weakest form of security and shouldn't be relied on. A proper solution in this case is basic authentication or token-based authentication.

Still, if an intruder has access to Angular application, he or she automatically gains access to API endpoints and can extract authentication information from the application.

Comment: Thanks, mate. That's what I wanna know. I already implemented the token authentication. Just want to hide some data that consumed by the Angular.

Comment: You can't hide anything if an intruder has access to the app. On the other hand, if you concerned by the fact that anyone can use this API on his/her website, that's another question, and this is solved by CORS.

Comment: Does that means all the Angular code is actually transparent to the users as it's on the client side?

Comment: Yes. There's no security in client side JS. If client side code should be secured, it has to be password-protected on server side (basic auth, etc).